# Syntax for PROC DELETE with memtype = VIEW

Tags: sas

According to the [PROC DELETE documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1469bsvzgd33jn0z4xecxmx2bgo.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

The following command should work

```
PROC DELETE LIBRARY=mylibrary DATA=myview MEMTYPE=VIEW
```

However, when actually using this I get:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting on of the following: a name, ;, (, -, '.'.
```

And then

```
Error 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored
```

Both errors are centered on the equal sign between memtype and view on the command above.

Could someone with more SAS experience tell me what I am doing wrong. Does PROC DELETE support deleting views?

If I just try to remove the memtype=view I get the warning:

```
File MYLIBRARY.MYVIEW.DATA does not exist.
```

I know there are ways to do this with other commands.. but is there a way to do this with PROC DELETE that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual says to use `()` around the options.

```
data myview / view=myview ;
  set sashelp.class ;
run;

proc delete data=myview (memtype=view);
run;
```

Looks like whoever added the enhancements to PROC DELETE when they took it out of mothballs didn't realize that most SAS statements that have options use a `/` to signal the start of the options and so they used this `()`.  It looks really strange since normally `()` following a member name is used to enclose dataset options.